# Как прикрутить авторизацию через ВК для приложения на Swift 2.3?

Tags: ios, swift, вконтакте

Саму библиотеку я подключил через pods. Подключил также vk_ios_sdk.framework в General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries. Затем в моём контроллере логина я импортировал vksdk:

```swift
import VK_ios_sdk
```

Добавил делегаты:

```swift
class LoginVC: UIViewController, VKSdkDelegate, VKSdkUIDelegate
```

Затем прописал id приложения, которое взял из настроек вк. А также прописал делегаты:

```swift
    let VK_APP_ID = "--" // Идентификатор Вашего VK-приложения

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let sdkInstance = VKSdk.initializeWithAppId(self.VK_APP_ID)
        sdkInstance.registerDelegate(self);
        sdkInstance.uiDelegate = self;
    }
```

Затем я реализовал все методы:

```swift
    // Методы протоколов VK SDK
    func vkSdkAccessAuthorizationFinishedWithResult(result:VKAuthorizationResult?) -> Void {
        print("vkSdkAccessAuthorizationFinishedWithResult = \(result)")
    }

    func vkSdkUserAuthorizationFailed() -> Void {
        print("vkSdkUserAuthorizationFailed")
    }

    func vkSdkAccessTokenUpdated(newToken:VKAccessToken?, oldToken:VKAccessToken?) -> Void {
        print("vkSdkAccessTokenUpdated = \(newToken)")
    }

    func vkSdkAuthorizationStateUpdatedWithResult(result:VKAuthorizationResult) -> Void {
        print("vkSdkAuthorizationStateUpdatedWithResult = \(result)")
    }

    func vkSdkShouldPresentViewController(controller:UIViewController?) -> Void {
        print("vkSdkShouldPresentViewController")
    }

    func vkSdkNeedCaptchaEnter(captchaError:VKError?) -> Void {

    }
```

`Print` в методах я вставил чисто чтобы отслеживать что где происходит. И сам логин я вызываю при нажатии кнопки:

```swift
    @IBAction func loginVKbtn(sender: UIButton) {
        let SCOPE = [VK_PER_EMAIL, VK_PER_NOHTTPS]

        VKSdk.initializeWithAppId(VK_APP_ID)
        VKSdk.authorize(SCOPE)
    }
```

Ещё я добавил ключи в plist файл (для доменов у меня уже там был ключ свой, я просто туда добавил ключ для вк):

```xml
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>vk</string>
        <string>vk-share</string>
        <string>vkauthorize</string>
    </array>

    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>frienddime.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>vk.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Я также ещё прочитал где-то, что нужно в appDelegate добавить функцию, но там было на swift 3, я попытался преобразовать в swift 2.3, но не знаю правильно ли, в любом случае от этого ни лучше ни хуже не стало. Вот код, который я добавил в appDelegate (в этом классе я тоже импортировал VK_ios_sdk):

```swift
    //MARK: - VKSdk setup
    //iOS 9 workflow
    func application(app: UIApplication, url: NSURL, options: NSDictionary) -> Bool {
        VKSdk.processOpenURL(url as NSURL, fromApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as! String)
        return true
    }
```

**В общем проблема**: при нажатии кнопки (которой я запускаю авторизацию) ничего не происходит, а лишь всплывает вот это сообщение - `canOpenURL: failed for URL: "vkauthorize://authorize" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"`

**Вопрос**: Что я делаю не так? Ведь как я понимаю, если не установлено приложение вк, то должен запуститься браузер? В симуляторе же вроде есть браузер, насколько я понял. Или всё-таки это только на реальном устройстве работает?

Ещё вопрос - где взять ios app id? В вк в настройках приложения надо добавлять этот id. Но я так и не понял где его взять. Мне подсказали, что это id приложения в аппсторе. Но моё приложение только в разработке. Или в вк пока не обязательно указывать этот id? Вот меня интересует вот это поле (1), а также поле (2), второе я заполнил, но на всякий случай уточните что туда писать, вдруг я неправильно его заполнил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDT:**
Вчера нагуглил, что чтобы открылась авторизация это надо реализовать самостоятельно в методе:

```swift
    func vkSdkShouldPresentViewController(controller:UIViewController?) -> Void {
        print("vkSdkShouldPresentViewController")
        presentViewController(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

После этого авторизация стала открываться. Протестили на реальном устройстве и при установленном приложении при первом нажатии запускается приложение вк и после подтверждения разрешения приложение вк запускает дальше страницу пользователя вк, что странно и никаких данных не возвращает. Если снова зайти в моё приложение и снова нажать логин, то в этот раз открывается сафари и там тоже можно подтвердить авторизацию, после чего выскакивает ошибка о невозможности открыть страницу. А в приложение возвращается результат, но все ключи nil.

Потом я на симуляторе тестил и при логине сафари всегда пишет, что нет доступа к странице (после разрешения авторизации) и типа надо проверить подключение к интернету. Но у меня все схемы вроде добавлены в plist (выше в тексте).

Comment: Хм, а Вас не напрягает фраза "Приложение отключено" ?

Comment: @RomanPodymov ну я не знаю на что эта настройка влияет, но андроид приложение работает. В приложении на андроиде пользователь точно так же авторизуется через вк и приложение получает токен и почту, по которым он либо регистрируется либо логинится на нашем сайте. Но в андроиде  не возникло трудностей. А вот в ios что-то не выходит. Хотя вчера добавил кое-что в код (я сейчас обновлю текст вопроса) и после этого стало запускаться приложение вк и там после подтверждения разрешения авторизации, просто переходило на страницу пользователя в вк и всё, а приложению ничего не возвращается.